# history option in android web app

Tags: android, android-webview

I am building an android web app using `WebView`, and I want to add a history feature to it.  I can't seem to find a solution anywhere else so if anyone can help me that would be great. How can I have the app save all the history in a new `Activity` 
`(History.java)`?

***activity_main.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="490dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/go"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/button_fix" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/go"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/go"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/go"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/type_url" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>`
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "blaze web view 2";
private WebView wv;
private Button go;
private EditText url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new BlazeWebViewClient());
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

    try {
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);
    go.setOnClickListener(this);

    url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    url.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.go:
        String theWebsite = url.getText().toString();
        if ((theWebsite.isEmpty())) {
            go.setText("GO");
            wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }

        else {
            theWebsite = "http://" + url.getText().toString();
            wv.loadUrl(theWebsite);
            go.setText("Home");
        }
        url.setText("");
        break;

    case R.id.editText1:
        go.setText("GO");
        Log.i("EDITTEXT", "EDIT TEXT WAS CLICKED");

    }

}

private class BlazeWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String Url) {
        webview.loadUrl(Url);
        return true;

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && wv.canGoBack()) {
        wv.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(TAG, "On Start");
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.i(TAG, "On Restart");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(TAG, "On Pause");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "On Resume");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "On Destroy");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i(TAG, "On Stop");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    wv.saveState(outState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSavedInstanceState");
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    wv.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "RestoreInstanceState");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.back:
        back();
        return true;

    case R.id.forward:
        forward();
        return true;

    case R.id.refresh:
        refresh();
        return true;

    case R.id.chistory:
        history();
        return true;
    case R.id.History:
        History();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

private void History() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, History.class);
    startActivity(i);

}

private void history() {
    wv.clearHistory();
    Log.i("H", "Cleared History");
}

private void refresh() {
    wv.reload();
    Log.i("R", "Page Reloaded");
}

private void forward() {
    wv.goForward();
    Log.i("F", "Page Foward");
}

private void back() {
    wv.goBack();
    Log.i("B", "Page Backward");
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for the [doUpdateVisitedHistory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#doUpdateVisitedHistory%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) and [getVisitedHistory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#getVisitedHistory%28android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%3E%29) APIs? The first one lets you know when a user went to a new page (so you can save it in your history database) and the second one (optional) lets you tell the WebView the contents of your history database so that the visited links have a different color. Your History activity would then have to read your history database and list the entries it contains.

Comment: I think thats what I need but I am just starting to make apps. what would I need to do to make the history show up on an xml using those to API's @marcin.koshiba